# When trying to specify a question on another site as a duplicate target, the error message displays incorrectly on sites with ampersands in their name

Tags: bug, status-review, duplicate-questions, error-message, html-entities

When flagging/VTCing a question as a dupe, and the link pasted into the box is from a different site, the error message looks like this:

> [image: Message which reads "The duplicate question must exist on Hinduism Stack Exchange"]

But on the 17 sites with ampersands in their titles (as well as their respective metas), it renders incorrectly with an `&amp;` instead.

Examples:

> [image: Message which reads "The duplicate question must exist on English Language & Usage Stack Exchange"]
> [image: Message which reads "The duplicate question must exist on Mythology & Folklore Stack Exchange"]

There seem to have been [similar bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22%26amp%3B%22) in the past.

Comment: Yes, there have been multiple similar bug reports. SE staff have told us that, for some reason, they have to fix each of these individually, so a separate bug report is required for each notification which has the problem of displaying undecoded HTML entities.